# How to get status bar text of Firefox 38 ESR in extension development?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I used to get status bar text with code

```
var text = tabBrowser.document.getElementById('statusbar-display').label;
```

but this line does not work in Firefox 38 ESR.

And also I cannot find any id related with status bar in DOM inspector.

Comment: The status bar was removed from Firefox in version 4 and replaced with the "Add-on Bar".  When the Australis theme was introduced in Fx 29, the add-on bar was also removed.  As far as I know, the only way to get it back is to use an extension such as "Status-4-Evar".

Comment: yeah, and the code above can work well until Fx 31 ESR. I see the element whose id is 'statusbar-display' in DOM inspector in Fx 24 but this element does not exist in Fx 31 and I cannot find similar element.

Comment: And I see the so-called 'status bar' is still there, when mouse over a html link, the url will display on the left bottom of the browser. I need to get this url in my extension. @ChuckBaker